# Get minimum from SQLite database column?

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I get the minimum value of an database column? 
I need to find the minimum `_id` of a SQLite table.

I tried the following, but had no success:

```
Cursor c = db.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE_LAST_REQUEST, new String[] { "min(" + KEY_ROWID + ")" }, null, null,
                    null, null, null);
int rowID = c.getInt(0);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What result does it give you? Does it through any exceptions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you call moveToFirst before getting the value:

```
Cursor c = db.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE_LAST_REQUEST, new String[] { "min(" + KEY_ROWID + ")" }, null, null,
                null, null, null);  
c.moveToFirst();  //ADD THIS!
int rowID = c.getInt(0);
```